# Error in listing tree structure using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tree, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to list a nested dictionary on html using ng-repeat

Here is the full [code](http://jsfiddle.net/w1nxqrn0/)

But it seems like I can't access the value of dictionary key by

```
tree.value
```

as it either doesn't show up or will only print

```
'tree.value'
```

Can someone help me out?

```
<div ng-app>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
      <li>X</li>
      <p>1 tree.value</p>
      <ul ng-repeat="tree in tree.children" ng-include="'myTemplate'">
          <p>2 tree.value</p>
      </ul>
  </script>
 <div>
     <ul ng-include="'myTemplate'"
    ng-init="tree = 
               {
        children: 
            [
                {children: [], value: c12}, 
                {
                    children: 
                        [
                            {children: [], value: c112}, 
                            {children: [], value: c111}
                        ],
                    value: c11
                }
            ], 
        value: c1
    }
"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You json is wrongly defined, you should always wrap string value inside single quotes `'` like `value: c111` & `value: 'c112'` values should be like `value: 'c111'` & `value: 'c112'`

**Markup**

```
    <ul ng-include="'myTemplate'"
        ng-init="tree = 
                   {
            children: 
                [
                    {children: [], value: 'c12'}, 
                    {
                        children: 
                            [
                                {children: [], value: 'c112'},
                                {children: [], value: 'c111'}
                            ],
                        value: c11
                    }
                ], 
            value: c1
        }
"></ul>
```

More better would be define `tree` variable inside `$scope` rather than on html.

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w1nxqrn0/1/)

Comment: Do you know why the `{{tree.value}}` have to be outside of `ul` tag instead of inside the `ul` tag?

Comment: @Kevin  because when `<ul ng-repeat="tree in tree.children" ng-include="'myTemplate'">`  tag doesn't have `tree.children` then that `ul` will not render by `ng-repeat` that why it should be out side that `ul`

Answer (score 0):

it seems c1 is object not string.so c1 has properties.for example c1 has text property.

you should write in template {{tree.value.text}}